# memoizing lodash isEqual or comparing prop objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to work with a component that updates the state to animate. To improve performance I added

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps) {
    return !isEqual(prevProps.properties, this.props.properties)
  }
```

to its child components.

`properties` is an object with up to 20 properties.

This improved performance significantly, however, `isEqual` is fairly expensive to run this much (up to 60x per second).

Does it make sense to memoize it, or is there a lighter alternative to running `isEqual` on every render while checking if the object is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't useful to memoize `isEqual` because it [already does strict equality check](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/baseIsEqual.js#L19-L20) for its parameters. If `prevProps.properties === this.props.properties`, there is no performance penalty.

In order to improve the performance of `shouldComponentUpdate` and avoid deep equality checks, `properties` prop should be immutable and use strict equality check:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps) {
    return prevProps.properties !== this.props.properties;
  }
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the concept of immutability, properties is an object from the state of a parent container, is it possible to make that immutable?

Comment: It is supposed be immutable because immutability is heavily promoted for a state in React, exactly because of this concern. If you intend to change `state.properties`, this should result in new object, `setState({ properties: {...} })`. This way you can always assume that if `prevProps.properties !== this.props.properties`, the object was changed.